# Why can't I use two DES keys that differ only in parity with OpenSSL?

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, openssl, pyopenssl

When I perform following action in terminal I get different decryption text compared to message showing that these keys map to unique cipher

```
openssl enc -des-ecb -in text.in -out cipher.txt -k '96508092'
openssl enc -d -des-ecb -in cipher.txt -out text.in -k '82514145'
```

But when I implement it in programming using `<openssl/des.h>`, Crypto.cipher, pyDes I got same decrypted text. I found why I get same text and it is because these 8 byte keys map to a unique 7 byte key 0x3832343134313401. Refer to my previous question [Why can I encrypt data with one DES key and successfully decrypt with another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216138/why-can-i-encrypt-data-with-one-des-key-and-successfully-decrypt-with-another)

My question is: how is it implemented on OpenSSL terminal commands differently compared to mentioned libraries that it could map these 8 byte keys to unique cipher?

Comment: @Duncan  I will be grate full if you have a look at this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an uppercase `-K` if you want to supply key bytes. Otherwise, OpenSSL assumes its a password and derives a (different) key from it.

You also need to use the hex versions of the keys:

```
openssl enc -des-ecb -in text.in -out cipher.txt -K '3832353134313435'
openssl enc -d -des-ecb -in cipher.txt -out text.out -K '3933353035303434'
```

Comment: @ceasif Did you use the hex versions of the keys (see final paragraph)? The example I showed above worked perfectly for me.

Comment: So how does openssl works with key as it is taking taking any size of key. What is the procedure to go to actual key here ..  openssl enc -d -des-ecb -in cipher.txt -out text.out -K '393335303530343412345123345677812345678812324'

Comment: @ceasif Not sure, I'm no OpenSSL expert. I'd guess it uses the first N bytes (where N is the required key length).

Comment: Thank you for sorting out. I will be glad to have your help in this quest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249256/openssl-is-acting-open-to-any-size-key