# openssl is acting open to any size key

Tags: cryptography, openssl, pyopenssl

how does openssl works with key as it is taking any size of key (1 byte to any size). What is the procedure to go to actual key here ..

```
openssl enc -d -des-ecb -in cipher.txt -out text.out -K '530343412312345445123345677812345678812324'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does openssl works with key ...  What is the procedure...

It depends on the program, but procedures are usually consistent across the library. In you example, you are using the `openssl dec`, so you are using the `dec` sub-program. The source code is available in `<openssl dir>/apps/enc.c` (`enc` and `dec` are part of `enc.c`).

Here's the relevant parts:

```
unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH],iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
unsigned char salt[PKCS5_SALT_LEN];
...
char *hkey=NULL,*hiv=NULL,*hsalt = NULL;
```

The argument to `-K` is stored in `hkey`:

```
else if (strcmp(*argv,"-K") == 0)
{
    if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
    hkey= *(++argv);
}
```

Then, around line 580:

```
if ((hkey != NULL) && !set_hex(hkey,key,sizeof key))
{
    /* Handle failure */
}
```

`set_hex` is shown below and hex decodes the argument passed in through `-K`. It back fills the unused length with 0's via the `memset`. The unused length is `EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH` minus the length `-K` argument (after hex decoding).

Finally, around line 610:

```
if (!EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv, enc))
{
    /* Handle failure */
}
```

**Note**: `-k` (small `k`) takes a different code path and uses `EVP_BytesToKey` to derive the key.

---

```
int set_hex(char *in, unsigned char *out, int size)
{
    int i,n;
    unsigned char j;

    n=strlen(in);
    if (n > (size*2))
    {
        BIO_printf(bio_err,"hex string is too long\n");
        return(0);
    }
    memset(out,0,size);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        j=(unsigned char)*in;
        *(in++)='\0';
        if (j == 0) break;
        if ((j >= '0') && (j <= '9'))
            j-='0';
        else if ((j >= 'A') && (j <= 'F'))
            j=j-'A'+10;
        else if ((j >= 'a') && (j <= 'f'))
            j=j-'a'+10;
        else
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"non-hex digit\n");
            return(0);
        }
        if (i&1)
            out[i/2]|=j;
        else
            out[i/2]=(j<<4);
    }
    return(1);
}
```

Comment: I could not actually figure out EVP_BytesToKey  derives a 8 byte key or actual 7 byte key for DES. The first approach, '-K' hex key takes 8 byte key and considers last bit of each byte as parity. Can you figure out this please

Answer (score 0):

My observation to the case gave following conclusion:

1. It takes hex value
2. If the size is less then 8 bytes it pads 0
3. It takes first 8 bytes as key