# How to set password for files or folders without encryption in c#?

Tags: c#, passwords

I encrypt my video files on DVD, when user want see videos, I decrypt video files on hard disk, then display to user. If user check the path of file, user can copy and use my films. How can I set a password to folder or files (video files) that user can't open or run folder / files ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a password protected file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740837/how-to-create-a-password-protected-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long does decryption take? If it's not too long, you could make a program that decrypts them when you want to run them and then decrypts them upon exit.

Either that or make your own folder viewing system that asks for a password for certain files.

Or one other option is to hide the files, then unhide them in the folders options, found using Windows Help And Support.